# What is the meaning of the sentence "The apocalypse of X"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I am not really a native English speaker. And so reading somewhere I found a sentence/phrase something like this of which I am not sure how to interpret the meaning correctly,

"The apocalypse of X". Where "X" is someone like Dave, James etc.

Does the sentence just mean X's apocalypse ? Or does it mean more of in the sense that "X" is doomed (or certain to die). Or are both meaning correct ?

Comment: Native speaker here (midwestern US).  I don't think I have ever seen that usage.

Comment: Of whom????  Of "John"? "The Apocalypse of John" refers to the last book in the New Testament (a.k.a. "Revelation").  Or, search "Apocalypse of" at Amazon and find many books with names like this.  I would say it means an "apocalypse" supposedly written by that person.

Comment: Can you give specific examples? Are you asking about early Christian texts?

Comment: If you look up [apocalypse on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse) you will find lots of information on the apocalypse as a literary genre. (Which makes me think this question may be more suited for Literature SE, whether it's about Judaeo-Christian texts, or more modern works.)

Comment: In that sense, it's like saying "The poetry of John"